# Error starting remote Bamboo agent: HTTP status code 500 received in response to fingerprint request

Tags: continuous-integration, bamboo

I have the following error when starting remote Bamboo agent:

```
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/20 01:15:58 | 2012-11-20 01:15:58,235 INFO [WrapperSimpleAppMain] [RemoteAgentHomeLocatorForBootstrap] Agent home located at '/Users/user9066/bamboo-agent-home'
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/20 01:15:58 | 2012-11-20 01:15:58,248 INFO [WrapperSimpleAppMain] [AgentUuidInitializer] Found agent UUID <snip> in temporary UUID file '/Users/user9066/bamboo-agent-home/uuid-temp.properties'
INFO   | jvm 1
    | 2012/11/20 01:15:58 | 2012-11-20 01:15:58,378 INFO [WrapperSimpleAppMain] [AgentContext] Requesting fingerprint, url: http://<bamboo-server-ip>:8090/bamboo/AgentServer/GetFingerprint.action?hostName=<remote-agent-ip>&version=3&agentUuid=<snip>
ERROR  | wrapper  | 2012/11/20 01:15:58 | JVM exited while starting the application.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/20 01:15:58 | Exiting due to fatal exception.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/20 01:15:58 | com.atlassian.bamboo.agent.bootstrap.RemoteAgentHttpException: HTTP status code 500 received in response to fingerprint request.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/20 01:15:58 |   at com.atlassian.bamboo.agent.bootstrap.AgentContext.initFingerprint(AgentContext.java:131)
```

The ports 8085 and 54663 are open. Enabling log4j does not provide any additional information too.

Has anyone seen this error? Any pointers to resolve this please?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error. I seemed to fix it by downloading the alternative remote agent installer called bamboo-agent-4.2.0.jar. You can find it as a small link underneath the main remote agent download button.

Once i had ran this jar and successfully authenticated, the original jar worked.

Comment: This suggestion fixed my problem right away! (I am using Bamboo 5.9.7 build 5920 - 14 Oct 15)